Heat equation two stage process - Additivity? some other approach?
I'm struggling a bit how to apply a standard solution to the heat equation to my own practical problem. I have some intuition, but do not know whether this intuition is justified. I don't understand the math well enough. My two questions are:

Is it correct to "scale and add" the partial solutions as I describe below? (if not, how can I solve it instead?)
What is the proper mathematical terminology to describe the solution? ("additivity"?)

My problem:
Suppose I put a hot sphere in a colder bath, and I want to know the temperature profile in the sphere. If the sphere starts out at homogeneous temperature, this problem has a standard solution. In non-dimensional form and for $\tau > 0.2$ we may approximate:
$$
 \frac{T(R) - T_{A}}{T_i - T_{A}} = \Theta_A(R,\tau) = A_1 e^{-\lambda_1^2\tau}\frac{\sin(\lambda_1 R)}{\lambda_1 R}
$$
Where $T_{A}$ temperature of the liquid in the batch,  $T_i$ the initial temperature of the sphere, $\Theta_A$ the dimensionless temperature, $R$ a positional coordinate that scales from 0 in the center to 1 at the surface of the sphere, $\tau$ the Fourier number a.k.a. dimensionless time, $\lambda_1$ the first eigenvalue of the heat equation and $A_1$ a constant that only depends on $\lambda_1$. For $\tau <0.2$ I need to add the second, third, etc. eigenvalue. I leave those out here for the sake of simplicity.
Now I take that sphere at some time $\tau_1 = \infty$, and place it in bath B, which has a temperature $T_{B} < T_{A}$. At $\tau_B = \infty$ I have $T(R) = T_A$ as initial condition, so I can re-use the previous solution with slight modification:
$$
 \frac{T(R) - T_{B}}{T_A - T_{B}} = \Theta_B(R,\tau) = A_1 e^{-\lambda_1^2\tau}\frac{\sin(\lambda_1 R)}{\lambda_1 R}
$$
So far, so good.
Now I change the situation. I don't wait until infinity, but I move that sphere to bath B at some time $\tau_B \ll \infty$. I now no longer have a homogeneous initial condition for the sphere that goes into bath B.
My intuition tells me that I can add both solutions, by re-mapping them to $\Theta_{overall} = \frac{T(R) - T_{B}}{T_i - T_{B}}$:
$$
\Theta_A(T_A) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \Theta_{overall}(T_A) = \frac{T_A - T_{B}}{T_i - T_{B}}
$$
$$\Rightarrow \Theta_{overall}(R,\tau) = \Theta_A(R,\tau)(1-\Theta_{overall}(T_A)) + \Theta_B(R,(\tau - \tau_B))\Theta_{overall}(T_A)$$
when $\tau - \tau_B > 0.2$.
It is easy for me to show that this works out if $\tau_B = 0$, and that the re-scaling works fine for the case where the bath B is entered with a sphere at homogeneous $T_A$. I am, however, at a loss when I want to show that I am justified to do this for $0 < \tau_B \ll \infty$.

Whenever I read "my intuition tells me" I'm starting to get scared.

Me too. Hence my question, hoping for a proper motivation.

Because the equation you're solving—the heat equation without power generation—is a linear homogeneous partial differential equation, you can superpose the results of boundary condition changes at different times. (For continuous changes, we obtain the convolution of the unit step response with the time-dependent boundary condition.)
This point is discussed is Carslaw & Jaeger's Conduction of Heat in Solids §1.14.II ("Surface conditions prescribed functions of the time.  No heat production").
So your intuited solution is valid, with the caveat that since you're using only the first term, the approximation is best for dimensionless time $\tau>0.2$, as you note. When the boundary conditions are undergoing step changes, do we need to wait for $\tau>0.2$ after each change? Let's check this by numerically solving the heat equation for your problem and comparing it to your analytical approximation.
I'll use an explicit finite-difference scheme, cooked up quickly in MS Excel, for the numerical solution. Suitable finite-difference approximations for a sphere are (from Crank's The Mathematics of Diffusion)
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial \tau}\to\frac{T_i^{t+1}-T_i^t}{\Delta\tau};$$
$$\nabla^2 T=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right)\to\begin{cases}\frac{1}{i(\Delta r)^2}\left[(i+1)T_{i+1}^t-2iT_i^t+(i-1)T_{i-1}^t\right] & (i\neq 0)\\ \frac{6}{(\Delta r)^2}(T_1^t-T_0^t) & (i=0),\end{cases}$$
where $i$ is the radial element number and $i=0$ corresponds to the sphere's center. (Note the special treatment of the center, which is obtained from applying L'Hôpital's rule to undefined $\frac{0}{0}$ terms at $r=0$; for excellent related discussion, see Hellevik's Numerical Methods for Engineers §7.7 "Example with radial symmetry".)
$T_i^{t+1}$ for each new time step is explicitly solved from the previous time step's information. The surface is held at the prescribed surface temperature. I used ten radial grid points ($\Delta r=0.1$) and found that $\frac{\Delta \tau}{(\Delta r)^2}\le\frac{1}{3}$ is required for stability of this explicit scheme at $r=0$. (Compare with $\frac{\Delta \tau}{(\Delta x)^2}\le\frac{1}{2}$ for rectangular coordinates; for a spherical-coordinate stability analysis, see Eisen's "On the numerical solution of $u_t=u_{rr}+\frac{2}{r}u_r$" and Hellivik's text mentioned above.)
Let's confirm that the scheme is operating correctly by checking the temperature change at the center for a unit temperature change at the surface:

As expected, using only the first series term results in relatively large errors for small $\tau$ but excellent agreement otherwise.
Now let's look at successive temperature changes of different amounts and different times:
A doubling of the initial temperature change:

A factor of ten:

A factor of one-tenth:

An earlier change in temperature:

We conclude that using only the first term requires waiting some time after each change, such that the additional terms scaling with higher powers of $e^{-\tau}$ become negligible, for the estimate to be suitably accurate.
Please let me know if you have any questions or would like to see other examples.

Thanks a lot. I appreciate the work that you put into this. Both a fundamental reason, which was what I was looking for, and some simulations to corroborate the fundamental answer. And as a bonus, a nice reference to reading materials! It will now be easy for me to apply it to my real situation. I know I can of course add as many terms as I need, depending on which $\tau$ I need to look at.

Any time, cheers!
